# Create sine wave and sample it in python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

So, I want to create a 1.95Khz signal, that is simple.

```
N=1024
```

`signal=[np.sin(2*np.pi*i/512)*20000+30000 for i in np.arange(0,N,1)]`

to have at least 2 periods.
How can I simulate that I am reading it back, using a sample frequency of 96Khz. I want 1024 samples.
Also when I send it out, each point is send every 1040ns( Each element of the signal array is send each 1040ns).

Comment: Avoid iterating explicitly over arrays and use array operations. `signal` can be written as:  `signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(N)/512)*20000+30000` This is much faster.

Comment: I think you would get more answers if you reframe you question in terms of algorithms than in terms of signal processing. Explain more explicitly what you want to to in numpy: "reading it back" and "send it out" is something I don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

```
N = 1024
ix = np.arange(N)
signal = np.sin(2*np.pi*ix/float(N/2))*20000+30000
time = ix/96e3
```

Then the vector time contains your sampling times, and signal contains your signal at these times.